# Convert a onedimensional Array to a multidimensional Array

Tags: arrays, powershell, multidimensional-array

I have an array in the following format:

```
C123456,
John Example,
C654321,
Mike Lastname,
C999999,
Elisabeth Average
```

Is there an easy way which I can convert that array to something like this:

```
CPName         Name
C123456        John Example
C654321        Mike Lastname
C999999        Elisabeth Average
```

Comment: Depends on your definition of easy :). You can certainly write code to do that. Where does the array come from?

Comment: It's going to be easiest to convert that to a hashtable (almost literally what such a thing is for) where names are linked to IDs or vice versa

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the array with step size 2 and build custom objects from all even indexes and their next neighbor:

```
$list = for ($i=0; $i -lt $arr.Count; $i+=2) {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        'CPName' = $arr[$i].TrimEnd(',')
        'Name'   = $arr[$i+1].TrimEnd(',')
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I have the problem that I can't use the properties of the hash in a foreach. Is this the normal behaviour? Here's the code I used:     
   `foreach($system in $systemNames){
        $systems += "'"
        $systems += $system.CPName
        $systems += "',"
    }`